# Raspberry Pi as a Intercom for live video

Tags: pi-2, video, audio-playback

I own a video productions company and want to know if it is possible to use 5 Pi's 1 at the directors switcher and one at each camera location to transmit audio so that I can call camera locations to the crew.  Each of the camera operators will need to be able to talk back to each other as well as talk to the director.

Comment: Take a look at this project. https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/talkiepi-raspberry-pi-walkie-talkie/ This is something similar to what you are trying to achieve. With a bit of hardware and software modifications, you should be able to communicate between all parties in no time by switching between different clients. The software however will have to be tested to see how it works and how it can be modified

Comment: Thanks Joachim this is good but I am looking at doing something that I can use headsets with.  The camera ops are going to need to be handsfree and sometimes environments are loud so they would need the headsets to muffle sound.

Comment: You can replace the USB speaker/mic used in this project with a suitable usb headset and mic?

Comment: Just buy some walkie talkies man!!! ... No, you wanna over engineer? OK! Setup a Asterisk server and use each Pi as VoiP client. If your network is stable enough (doesn't have to be brilliant) you can use basic encoding like GSM. You can also configure asterisk to work like a push-to-talk service. None of this is easy though but once it set up you can do amazing things with it. Or.. you can get walkie talkies...

Comment: I'm not sure about the concept. Your options are really old-school radio or some kind of Voice Over IP (VOIP). Mumble (used in @JoachimPrinsloo's linked tutorial above) looks like an OK choice for VOIP, although I notice that it had to be tweaked specifically for the Pi which doesn't bode well for the solution's longevity. Using VOIP is reliant on an immortal, secure, powerful WiFi signal throughout your installation - any failure of the connection means no talkback between any parties, which is potentially catastrophic.

Comment: If you go the Pi route, rather than just buying some walkie talkies, you're manufacturing talkback devices with a 10-20 second boot time. I've done some studio and theatre work, and that's *not a good idea*.

Comment: VoIP doesn't really need excellent WiFi. If you setup your own asterisk server you can fine-tune jitter control, packet delay assembly, etc etc. You can just drop packets straight away like on normal mobiles where you may loose parts of a word, just using UDP GSM will work OK on a patchy 802.11a network. Actually even a single channel GPRS can handle it for one way streaming OK, but, why?

Comment: @ppumpkin Sounds like the setup'll need 5 duplex/10 simplex always-on channels. It's not *massive* but working with mushy headsets is a nightmare in loud places - I'd want some headroom for a somewhat-excessive datarate so I could get nice definition on plosives and sibilants. I was more talking about 'powerful' as it relates to range. If I'd built the setup, and was likely to be the one everyone looks at when everything stopped working, I think I'd like it to work out to something like 500 metres. Just. In. Case.